# Hyperref `mailto` adds extra slashes

Tags: hyperref, email

I have the following:

```
\href{mailto:amail@mail.xyz}{amail@mail.xyz}}
```

which upon click within the Editor's native document viewer is being rendered in the default email client as

> ///amail@mail.xyz

The issue remains consistent regardless of the TeX Editor in use. Am I missing something?

*Note:* There is no problem, when accessing the link from the generated PDF, outside of the given editor.

Comment: ...and what might be the name of this ominous TeX editor?

Comment: Could it be that it is not `hyperref`s fault but the sole reason for this is the editor doing *magic*?

Comment: @Werner Both Texmaker and TeXworks.

Comment: @Skillmon Yes, I believe so, because on a generated PDF works just fine, but within the editors it fails.

Comment: @user8: This is clearly specific to the editor/internal viewer and should therefore be posted as a bug (or feature request). For that reason, this is off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Test file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{mailto:amail@example.org}{amail@example.org}
\end{document}
```

The URI in the PDF file, generated by `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, or `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf`:

```
/URI(mailto:amail@example.org)
```

The URI is correct, no slashes. The problem is probably the viewer that does not know, how to handle the `mailto:` protocol.

Comment: So then this question has nothing to do with TeX/LaTeX and is therefore off topic?

Comment: @Werner IMHO, the question is not clear enough to decide this, something between OK, unclear, and off topic.

Comment: It's clearly related to a specific subset of (internal) viewers. I've voted to close as off-topic with the suggestion to post a bug report/feature request, as that would be the only way really that it can be fixed.